# Removing a certificate from the local machine certificate store in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to check for, and then remove a certificate if it exists in a user's local machine store.  I've tried this:

```bsh
$certCN = 'test.domain.com'
Set-Location Cert:\LocalMachine\My
$oldCert = Get-ChildItem -Recurse | 
Where-Object { $_.subject -like "CN=$oldCert*" }
Remove-Item Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$oldCert -Force
```

But it is not removing the cert from the store or giving any errors (yes I am running this elevated).

I checked my `$oldCert` variable to see if it is populated and it is:

```
PS Cert:\LocalMachine\My> $oldcert
PSParentPath: Microsoft.PowerShell.Security\Certificate::LocalMachine\My

Thumbprint                                Subject                                                                                                                                                                       
----------                                -------                                                                                                                                                                       
276B7B87740D5E9595A258060F5CD9CC4190E9E1  CN=test.domain.com, <truncated>
```

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?  I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're working with a certificate **_object_**, not string. -> `$oldCert | Remove-Item`

Comment: That did it.  Thank you very much for the explanation.  Still getting my bearings with scripting and didn't even realize by fully pathing that out I was calling a string vs. the actual certificate object, but it makes sense now.  Thanks again!

Comment: Three things you need to know: `Get-Help`, `Get-Command`, and `Get-Member`.

Comment: Thank you!  I had no idea about get-member!  Tremendously helpful.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem you're encountering is the automatic string conversion of the `X509Certificate2` object from the `Cert:\` drive.  When you're appending it to your path as `-Path some\path\$myobj`, it's implicitly calling `ToString` on the object.  You can observe this by doing `"some\path\$myobj"` at the console without any other code or by simply calling `$myobj.ToString()`.

Because `Remove-Item` takes pipeline input by property name, it will automatically pull the path off your object when you pass it over the pipeline, so you can remediate your problem simply as such:

```
$oldCert | Remove-Item
```

or

```
Remove-Item -LiteralPath $oldCert.PSPath
```